# Cucumber RestAssured Report with Request Response

Tags: maven, cucumber, rest-assured

I am trying to generate Cucumber reports for Rest-Assured (RESTful API) and I am also keen to capture request / response in the cucumber reports. I was wondering if anybody has already implemented this or can provide some pointers.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68842731/3059685) shows how you can use RestAssured filters to capture the Request/Response details in your cucumber report.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Gherkin/BDD with [QAF](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws) for web service testing and in the report it gives request and response for each request.